# Can an object be cast to two unrelated types?

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I'm receiving an object that can only ever be one of two known types - let's call them 'typeA' and 'typeB'. These two types are not related to each other.

I need to find the correct type before I can use the object. Here's some code showing my initial attempt to find the proper type:

```
    public void OneOfTwoTypes(object obj)
    {
        try 
        { 
            var objType = (typeA)obj; 
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            var objType = (typeB)obj; 
        }

        // extra code for doing things to this object. 

    }
```

The above code wouldn't run because of scoping. And I couldn't declare var as a null either. So I went with dynamic instead:

```
    public void OneOfTwoTypes(object obj)
    {
        dynamic objType;
        try 
        { 
            objType = (typeA)obj; 
        }
        catch (InvalidCastException)
        {
            objType = (typeB)obj; 
        }

        // extra code for doing things to this object. 

    }
```

This runs fine and does the job. My question is - is there a better way of doing this ? Also, not having used dynamic before, are there any major issues with my current implementation ?

**Edit**: Adding a bit of commentary around what the object is being used for.
The typeA and typeB objects implement similar properties but represent different physical entities (one represents applied pressure while the other represents point loadings). For the code above, I will be using properties that are very similar (e.g. typeA.propertyA represents pressure loads from snow and is conceptually similar as typeB.propertyA in that both are from snow loading but the latter refers to point loads instead. Note that the two do have some properties that are different).

The end output will be a calculation for load combinations - which will include the same sort of calculations regardless of whether typeA or typeB is being used.

I don't want to use method overloads as that will involve significant amounts of copying of the same code for both object types (we're talking hundreds of lines here). I do like the idea of an interface which both types implement.

Comment: The better way is to introduce an interface that typeA and typeB both implement.

Comment: I don't get it: if you don't know the type once you are outside the `try`, what do you propose to actually do with the object? Please explain what you are trying to achieve once you have casted. Aside: you should use `as` to safely cast without throwing an exception, or better, `is typeA objType` to assign it straight into a variable

Comment: With `dynamic objType`, you don't have to cast `object obj`, you can just assign it to `dynamic`. [The question is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640), what does the casting give you? Do you then call different methods on these objects depending on their type?

Comment: The answer to your literal question is found in the duplicates (and many others). There's not enough context in your question to know whether the solution you've decided to use is actually appropriate. For example, if the caller of this method already has the correct type, then using method overloads is much better than runtime type checking. If the objects have similar functionality, then using an interface if much better than runtime type checking. Frankly, almost anything is much better than runtime type checking. Occasionally, it can't be avoided, but most of the time it can.

Comment: Thanks for the advice all. I've added an edit to explain a bit more. I do like your recommendation @mjwills so might head in that direction.

Comment: @Andorrax typed languages like C# work best when it knows what types it's working with - avoid falling back to `object` whenever possible. An interface seems like the best thing in this scenario - one which exposes the raw numbers that go through the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

First, c# isn't really build to pass objects around as objects. one of the biggest benefits of a strongly typed language is that there aren't any surprises it terms of getting an array object when I want a list, or vise versa. You're first option should be a shared interface that both can implement that you can pass around as the interface instead of the explicit implementation.

Sometime that doesn't always work, though. and in that case you do still have options.

A language like c# also knows the object type in runtime. The basic api for this is `obj.GetType() == typeof(TypeA)`, but that only evaluates to true if the type is the same and does not consider inheritance relationships or interface impelmentations. The starting point would then be `obj is TypeA`, which returns `true` if object can be assigned the type `TypeA`, else `false`. This can be used in an if statement as well (see below).

You can also use a [pattern matching switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/may/csharp-8-0-pattern-matching-in-csharp-8-0) from C# 8, if you need to test more that one or two types.

```cs
// we'll pretend for this example that array and list of 2 completely different objects that need to be handled in code in completely different ways
var obj = new Random().Next(2) == 1
    ? (IEnumerable<Guid>) new []{ Guid.NewGuid() }
    : new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid() };

// option 1: if statements with `is` keyword
if (obj is List<Guid> list)
{
    // the variable list in in scope in the if block, since it was declared in the if statement
    HandleList(list);
}
else if (obj is Guid[] array)
{
    // the variable array is in scope in the else block
    HandleArray(array);
}


// option 2: pattern matching switch
switch (obj) 
{
    case List<Guid> list:
        HandleList(list);
        break;
    case Guid[] array:
        HandleArray(array);
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```